# How can I design an Android interface that support different screen size?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, mobile

I want that my android app support different screen size, so what is best practice to do these, how should I choose the sizes of textView and button and Should I design different layout for every screen size?

Answer (score 1):

Best way of doing that is design separate XML for (small, medium, large and X-large) screen sizes. While creating XML layout file pass a size qualifier.

Do not hardcode sizes always use match parent or wrap content.

When specifying dimensions, always use either dp or sp units. sp is a scale-independent pixel used for text sizes. The sp scale factor depends on a user setting and the system scales the size the same as it does for dp.

For images use 9 patch images. you can generate them from [here](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html#&sourceDensity=320&name=example)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
android:layout_weight="x";
```

This will help you if you specify the weight of each view.

Comment: You should probably be a little more specific, plus there are pitfulls to using layout weights, especially when nested. And maybe explain how this solution is relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can get details from this documentation it is very relevant to what you are asking:

[Supporting Multiple Screen](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

The key idea is to have different layout files for tablets and small devices that will be loaded for different screen configurations.

Also make sure you do not use AbsoluteLayout because it has problems resizing.

Define metrics by dpi's rather than pixels. It helps to avoid losing resolution when screen size gets larger.

Other than these, all important things are in the documentation.